# Follow up to posted questions

Tags: support, feature-request, questions

Is there a mechanism for a poster to follow-up their question with the results of actions taken based on what was learned here? I'm thinking specifically of GM Techniques questions, but I suspect other tags could benefit as well. Many of the "How do I do this?" and "I have this problem..." posts have interesting and creative answers, and I think it would be instructive to get the OP to provide feedback on what was tried and what worked or didn't and why.

If there is no current device for this, perhaps we could either provide a mechanism to add a "Follow-up" section to the post construct in addition to the original "Question" and "Answers" sections, or institute a common practice of returning and amending the original question statement with an "OP's Follow-up" blurb.

I'll confess, while I do in fact believe this would be instructional and improve the usefulness of our posts, sometimes I just want to know "the rest of the story".  (I probably watch too many "save my business" reality shows...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No there isn't, and I doubt it is likely to be added.  There are a few ways you could currently do what you want:

- Poster Edit's the question:  This works well if they attempted a solution and it failed, so they need further input.
- Poster answers the question: This works well if a hybrid approach from several answers worked (common in my experience).
- Poster comments the answer that works: This works well if one answer handled it.  However it's not very visible to the community at large.

Comment: Maybe I'll just start advocating for the OP to provide one of these types of responses whenever I answer one and hope it catches on.

Answer (score 6):

There is, in fact, a device just for this!

It's the accept check mark on the left of every answer. Ideally the OP of the question is encouraged to accept *the answer that works best for them*. So if they actually implement a solution from one of the answers they should mark it as accepted.

Comment: Although I suspect many OPs will accept the one they're gonna try first, then never update that even if they come back to try other answers.

Comment: that's what we live with